# Toggle show/hide (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are many posts on this topic already but none that address my issue directly. Here is my current setup:

I have a div with the ID `#ptwesv`;

and another div containing the content I want to show hide with the ID `#ptwest`.

The jQuery I'm using is this:

```
<script>
jQuery("#ptwesv").click(function(){
    jQuery("#ptwest").show();
});
jQuery("#ptwesv").click(function(){
    jQuery("#ptwest").hide();
});
</script>
```

This is hiding the `#ptwest` container correctly on click, but then doesn't show the conatiner when I click the trigger element (`#ptwesv`) again. I presume this is because once the element has been hidden, clicking on the trigger again is causing the actions to work against each other.

I'm using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show) W3 exmaple as a reference, the only salient different I notice is that there are different trigger elements for show/hide.

**Is it possible to trigger show/hide of an element from the a single div and how can I get this to work?**

Comment: `jQuery("#ptwest").toggle()`

Comment: You're overwriting your first click event when you're setting the second. All given answers so far would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery("#ptwesv").click(function(){
    jQuery("#ptwest").toggle();
});
```

is the way you want. It toggles the element. So if it is shown it hides and the other way around.

At the moment the element will always hide, because of twice the same click element.

Answer (score 3):

Because `Id` is unique for whole document. try  with [`toggle()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiKyP3ogv_UAhUJU7wKHcWoBzEQFggtMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ftoggle%2F&usg=AFQjCNGiXJSQEIu9ZI5hjngqbTYaL5OB9g)

```js
jQuery("#ptwesv").click(function(){
    jQuery("#ptwest").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh my answer is the same and was 1 minute earlier.. :(

Comment: I wouldn't use .toggle() - if the user clicks the same element fast enough, jQuery toggle fails and you end up with mixed results. I always use .show() and .hide() in combination with a boolean that stores the current state of the element. (if it's shown or hidden when the listener is called).

Comment: @RickBronger ahhh I hadn't noticed, up vote coming your way :)

Answer (score 0):

The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements.

This method checks the selected elements for visibility. show() is run if an element is hidden. hide() is run if an element is visible - This creates a toggle effect.

```
   $("#ptwesv").click(function(){
       $("#ptwest").toggle();
   });
```